# Is there a tool to do "next speech prediction"?

Tags: nlp, text-to-speech

Given the enormous success of next-token prediction, I was wondering if there are any successful models that try to apply the same principle on speech, i.e., the analogue audio of speech rather than only the text. There are obviously a lot more information in speech, in comparison to text, so there is more to be learned.